# Prevent ListView from changing selection when mouse moved with button down

Tags: wpf, listview, mouseevent

I have a ListView with Extended SelectionMode. By default when I press a left button down it selects an item and when I move the mouse cursor (slowly) it moves the selection (as long as the button is still down).

Since I am implementing Drag and Drop on top of the list it becomes a little annoying. How can I prevent it from changing a selected item when a mouse button is down? I've tried to say e.Handled=true in the PreviewMouseMove but it didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**
The last solution was not working. This is a combo of two events that disables the mousemove selection. The problem is that when selecting an already selected item (no SelectionChanged occurs) then we can still move the mouse up or down to change the selection. The only way I found to get around this was to trick the ListView into selecting the same item again. This might be inconvenient if you have functionality for selection changed but otherwise this seems to get the job done.

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Extended"
            Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="listViewItem_Selected"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="listViewItem_PreviewMouseDown"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

And in the EventHandlers

```
void listViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listView.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
private void listViewItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem listViewItem = sender as ListViewItem;
    if (listViewItem.IsSelected == true)
    {
        // Unselecting the item in the Preview event
        // "tricks" the ListView into selecting it again
        listViewItem.IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works a little better but still not 100%, now if I move the mouse FAST but just one item down the list it still selects it. Looks like SelectionChanged is called before the PreviewMouseMove.

Comment: You are right, it still fails when selecting the same item twice. I tried printing out every ReleaseMouseCapture and it is indeed called, but the ListView still change item on MouseMove

Comment: I would have more time to try your answer if you didn't put projecteuler.net link in your profile.

Comment: I read your comment and thought that you meant that it's bad manners to link to another site in the profile. Reading it again it sounds like you checked it out and liked it :) I'm pretty new here so.. Is it bad manners to link to another site in the profile like that?

Comment: Absolutely not a bad manner. It's a great link! I am stuck solving those puzzles instead of doing real work.

Comment: Haha ok :) Yes, that site is awesome! Good luck on the puzzle solving

Comment: You solution works in a standalone window however i am still having issues because of my drag-n-drop. I just need to be careful to merge all those even handlers. Thanks!